# gradle script classpath contains only script class

Tags: postgresql, gradle, classpath

trying to add jdbc postgresql driver to gradle script, i used the bildscript.dependencies.classpath DSL but groovy.sql.Sql cannot find it. so i tried printing the classpath:
`((URLClassLoader)this.class.classloader).getURLS.each{
    println("#### ${it}")
}`

all that was printed was the directory where the gradle temp compiled files reside, so where are all the rest of the directories ? jar ?
BTW i can in my script use import and instantiate classes from the postgres sql package.
my guess is that the sql packages looks for the class in the wrong classloader, same as me, so anyone knows how to get a hold of the class loader ? will instantiating the driver and adding it to the DriverManager solve the issue ?

Comment: looking at DriverManager sourcecode it seems that even if i manually register a driver in DriverManager by instantiating it myself it still wont help as it verifies that the classloader it found can load this class. the getClassLoader method is native and so it's hard to find it's code. i'll use the damn GroovyObject.class.classLoader hack that loads the same classes into the local classpath and be done with it, but i still don't understand how the classpath is orginized in gradle :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome problems with `DriverManager` in my Gradle script which essentially is a Groovy script. I had to do the equivalent of

```
GroovyObject.class.classLoader.addURL(new File('path/to/jar/with/sql/driver.jar').toURI().toURL())
Class.forName('foo.bar.sql.Driver')
```

to be able to do `Sql.newInstance dbConnectionString, dbUser, dbPassword` afterwards.

Maybe this helps you to get it running for you too.

Comment: can't recall what was the correct answer eventually but the runtime classpath is somehow different without injection like u extra thing into the path it's just doesn't work and i hate these kind of hacks, specifically here there's no choice. So i'll accept your answer :-)